# R - Extract temporally independent events from dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to extract and keep only records which are considered as temporally independent events from each other.

Temporally independent events are here classified as any event (row in data frame) that took place for the same category (column: "cat"), at the same location (column: "loc"), within a given time period from each other. The time period is set to 1800 seconds (i.e., 30 minutes). For example, if category "X" was recorded at location "1" within 1800 seconds of another event for the same category (i.e., "X") at the same location (i.e., "1"), then only the first record should be kept. Whereas, in category "X" was recorded at location "1" with a difference of 1801 seconds in time between the two or more consequtive events, then it would be kept as two records.

I hope this description makes sense?

Below are some example data:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    cat = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), 
    loc = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4), 
    date_time = structure(c(1609451755, 1609452355, 1609581600, 1609582202, 1609583403, 1609585200, 1609668005, 1609538155, 1609841700, 1609495204, 1609583406, 1609668000, 1609539071, 1609756205, 1609758001, 1609581600, 1609668067, 1609451793, 1609452213, 1609452633, 1609495200, 1609626404, 1609581600), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    date = structure(c(18627, 18628, 18629, 18629, 18629, 18629, 18630, 18628, 18632, 18628, 18629, 18630, 18629, 18631, 18631, 18629, 18630, 18627, 18628, 18628, 18628, 18630, 18629), class = "Date"), 
    time = c("23:55:55", "00:05:55", "12:00:00", "12:10:02", "12:30:03", "13:00:00", "12:00:05", "23:55:55", "12:15:00", "12:00:04", "12:30:06", "12:00:00", "00:11:11", "12:30:05", "13:00:01", "12:00:00", "12:01:07", "23:56:33", "00:03:33", "00:10:33", "12:00:00", "00:26:44", "12:00:00")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data look like this when printed in the console:

```
> df
   cat loc           date_time       date     time
1    X   1 2020-12-31 23:55:55 2020-12-31 23:55:55
2    X   1 2021-01-01 00:05:55 2021-01-01 00:05:55
3    X   1 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00
4    X   1 2021-01-02 12:10:02 2021-01-02 12:10:02
5    X   1 2021-01-02 12:30:03 2021-01-02 12:30:03
6    X   1 2021-01-02 13:00:00 2021-01-02 13:00:00
7    X   2 2021-01-03 12:00:05 2021-01-03 12:00:05
8    X   3 2021-01-01 23:55:55 2021-01-01 23:55:55
9    X   3 2021-01-05 12:15:00 2021-01-05 12:15:00
10   Y   1 2021-01-01 12:00:04 2021-01-01 12:00:04
11   Y   1 2021-01-02 12:30:06 2021-01-02 12:30:06
12   Y   2 2021-01-03 12:00:00 2021-01-03 12:00:00
13   Y   3 2021-01-02 00:11:11 2021-01-02 00:11:11
14   Y   3 2021-01-04 12:30:05 2021-01-04 12:30:05
15   Y   3 2021-01-04 13:00:01 2021-01-04 13:00:01
16   Y   4 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00
17   Z   2 2021-01-03 12:01:07 2021-01-03 12:01:07
18   Z   3 2020-12-31 23:56:33 2020-12-31 23:56:33
19   Z   3 2021-01-01 00:03:33 2021-01-01 00:03:33
20   Z   3 2021-01-01 00:10:33 2021-01-01 00:10:33
21   Z   3 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-01 12:00:00
22   Z   3 2021-01-03 00:26:44 2021-01-03 00:26:44
23   Z   4 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00
```

What I want is some code that could transform it to this:

```
> df_wanted
   cat loc           date_time       date     time
1    X   1 2020-12-31 23:55:55 2020-12-31 23:55:55

3    X   1 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00

5    X   1 2021-01-02 12:30:03 2021-01-02 12:30:03

7    X   2 2021-01-03 12:00:05 2021-01-03 12:00:05
8    X   3 2021-01-01 23:55:55 2021-01-01 23:55:55
9    X   3 2021-01-05 12:15:00 2021-01-05 12:15:00
10   Y   1 2021-01-01 12:00:04 2021-01-01 12:00:04
11   Y   1 2021-01-02 12:30:06 2021-01-02 12:30:06
12   Y   2 2021-01-03 12:00:00 2021-01-03 12:00:00
13   Y   3 2021-01-02 00:11:11 2021-01-02 00:11:11
14   Y   3 2021-01-04 12:30:05 2021-01-04 12:30:05

16   Y   4 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00
17   Z   2 2021-01-03 12:01:07 2021-01-03 12:01:07
18   Z   3 2020-12-31 23:56:33 2020-12-31 23:56:33


21   Z   3 2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-01 12:00:00
22   Z   3 2021-01-03 00:26:44 2021-01-03 00:26:44
23   Z   4 2021-01-02 12:00:00 2021-01-02 12:00:00
```

Above you can see the gaps where a row was removed because it was within the 1800 sec threshold, at the same location, for the same category.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is close to what you want. `filter(df, !(cat == lag(cat) & loc == lag(loc) & date_time - lag(date_time, default = as.Date("2020-01-01")) < 30))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `difftime` to calculate time difference between consecutive `date_time` values and keep only the rows that have difference greater than 30 mins within each `cat` and `loc`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(cat, loc) %>%
  filter(as.integer(difftime(date_time, lag(date_time), units = 'secs')) > 1800 | row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, the code above is very close but it is removing some extra rows. I think that it is happening with the `lag` function, where if there is more than one event that falls within the 1800 sec threshold, then it calculates the difference between the two consecutive events but ignores any events just before that. 

My apologies if my explanation is badly worded. Basically if there are one or more events (at a given station,for a given category) after a event, then if these event(s) happened within a 1800 sec period then only the first event within this group of events is kept.

Comment: I think I am confused. Can you explain with an example? Does that happen for the data that you have shared?

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this is ver difficult to explain.. But if you look in the provided data at row 5, you will notice that the code you provided removed this line as well, but in fact row 5 should stay because it is within the 1800 sec threshold from the previous independent event (i.e., row 3) but the code is only looking at the previous event and comparing to that (i.e., row 4). I'm not sure, does this make more sense? Please let me know

Comment: Ronak and I were on the same path (our code produces the same output). You don't need to call `difftime` explicitly since objects with class datetime dispatch a method for `-` that understands how to subtract times. Still working on getting what the OP wanted...